# SPARQL query to retrieve data with different datatype (string)

Tags: string, sparql, rdf

I am writing a SPARQL query to retrieve answers for the competency question. I want to retrieve all persons who have level of distress "not too disturbing".

```
select *
where
{
  ?person ocd:hasInsight  ?insight;
  ocd:hasThought ?thought;
  ocd:hasEmotion ?emotion;
  ocd:hasDistressLevel ?severitycontrol.
  FILTER (?severitycontrol = ocd:Not too disturbing) 
}
```

I am new at this and could not figure out how to fix that.

Comment: If `ocd:hasDistressLevel` is a string then you should get all persons with this query:
`select * where {
    ?person ocd:hasDistressLevel "Not too disturbing" 
}`
You can add more details to it of course.

Comment: really appreciate that

Comment: You need to provide more context. What does the ocd prefix expand to?  What is the content of the triplestore or rdf dataset? Does it use an ontology? We don’t have enough information to answer without guessing these things

Answer (score 1):

If the value is a string (e.g., `"Not too disturbing"`):

```
FILTER (?severitycontrol = "Not too disturbing") .
```

If the value is language-tagged in your RDF, you have to append that same language tag:

```
FILTER (?severitycontrol = "Not too disturbing"@en) .
```

String matching is case-sensitive. You can use [`ucase`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-ucase)/[`lcase`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lcase) to make a string uppercase/lowercase.

If you only want to match a partial string, you can use [`strStarts`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts)/[`strEnds`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strends), [`contains`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains), [and more](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strings).

Comment: IF I want to retrieve patient with associated value (individual of other classes) such as patients who has a mild distress, and mild distress is an individual of a class. How can I formulate the SPRQL query. Apologies for asking again

Comment: or I want to retrieve patient with mild to moderate distress

Comment: @Areej: Instead of a string, you have to use the URI of the individual then. `FILTER (?severitycontrol = ocd:MildDistress) .`